# PhpStorm local directory autocomplete

Tags: windows, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have in one directory of project two folders (in fact, much more). In these folders I have independent projects, for example SCSS. And when I start type variable name (or filename) in autocomplete window I have too many variables from another SCSS projects.

How to prevent get autocomplete from these folders, but not from current SCSS project?

Is helpful function exist or I only need separate all these directories in 'directories' section in settings?

```
PROJECT DIRECTORY
├───Folder A
│   ├───Scss folder
├───Folder B
│   ├───Another scss folder
...
├───Folder Z+
│   ├───Another scss folder
```

Comment: You could change the scope of autocomplete by directory in setting, or right click directory > Mark as > excluded to not interfere between folder

Comment: But this way i'm always must do "mark/unmark" on change working scss folder? It's not conveniently if i need work on several folders in one time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment. The only workarounds are marking folders as Excluded or changing working folders.
Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25628.